# parse JSON object passed through Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, pdo

I'm trying to parse a information that gets returned from a DB and encoded into a JSON object.

this is the code that retrieves the information:

```
   private function retrieve_standards_one(){
    $dbh = $this->connect();
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT code, standard_one_id 
                           FROM standard_one 
                           WHERE grade_id = :grade_id 
                           ORDER BY standard_one_id");
    $stnd = array();
    for($x = 0; $x < (count($this->grades)); $x++){                    
    $stmt->bindParam(':grade_id', $this->grades[$x], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stnd[] = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
    $json = json_encode($stnd);
    return $json;
}
```

and this id how I'm trying to parse the information:

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "lib/search/search.standards_one.php",
        async: "false",
        data: {subjects: subjects, grades: grades},
        success: function(response){
                $("#standards_results").html("");
                var obj = $.parseJSON(response);
                $.each(obj, function(){
                    alert(this['code'] + ", " + this['standard_one_id'])
                });
            }
        });
```

I've tried a number of different ways to do this, but I only ever get [object][object] as a response.

this is the response:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4R3V.png

Comment: `[object Object]` is the default string representation of objects, so your code is probably working correctly. `alert` is a **very bad** debugging tool, use `console.log` instead if you want to inspect variables. And don't concatenate objects with strings!

Comment: consol.log still just returns the [objects]s

Comment: Did you remove the string concatenation? Do `console.log(this['code']); console.log(this['standard_one_id'])`. Both, `alert` and string concatenation will convert objects to strings, which is what you should avoid.

Comment: Yes I ran:
consol.log(this['code'], this['standard_id']);

Comment: add `dataType:'json'` to `$.ajax` options and jQuery will automatically manage the  JSON parsing. `response` will be array or object depending on what is sent from server. Don't use `async:false`

Comment: I already told you that `alert` is the wrong tool for debugging/inspecting and yet you used it to make the screenshot. Please post the output of `console.log(obj)` and `console.log(response)`.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
console.log(this['code'] , this['standard_one_id'])
```

Instead of

```
alert(this['code'] + ", " + this['standard_one_id'])
```

Comment: It should rather be `console.log(this['code'], this['standard_one_id'])`. If you keep the string concatenation, it won't make much of a difference.

Comment: Yes, It can give a better output

Comment: consol.log still just returns the [objects]s

Comment: Did you try logging your ajax response

Comment: Can post the response too in your question?

Comment: I added the response to the original question

Comment: I mean the responseText from ajax :)

Answer (score 0):

Add dataType attribute to your AJAX call.

$.ajax ({

```
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    url: "lib/search/search.standards_one.php",
    async: "false",
    data: {subjects: subjects, grades: grades},
    success: function(response){
            $("#standards_results").html("");
            var obj = $.parseJSON(response);
            $.each(obj, function(){
                alert(this['code'] + ", " + this['standard_one_id'])
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: If you do that, you have to remove `$.parseJSON(response);`. Besides I don't think it will make any difference. You simply change the moment when the response is parsed.